# What does "Recheck Cond" in Explain result mean?

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

From an example in PostgreSQL document:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tenk1 WHERE unique1 < 100 AND stringu1 = 'xxx';
                                  QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on tenk1  (cost=5.04..229.43 rows=1 width=244)
   Recheck Cond: (unique1 < 100)
   Filter: (stringu1 = 'xxx'::name)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tenk1_unique1  (cost=0.00..5.04 rows=101
 width=0)
         Index Cond: (unique1 < 100)
```

Am I correct that

- first perform Bitmap Index Scan on all the rows for the first condition, and
- then on the returned rows, perform Bitmap Heap Scan for the second condition?

Since Bitmap Index Scan already checks the Index Cond on unique1 < 100, why is there "Recheck Cond" on the same condition again in Bitmp heap Scan?
What does "Recheck Cond" mean?

I am not sure I understand this related post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106264/recheck-cond-line-in-query-plans-with-a-bitmap-index-scan

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This was explained by [Tom Lane](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12553.1135634231@sss.pgh.pa.us) on the mailing list:

> > *what is "Recheck condition" and why is it needed?*
>
> If the bitmap gets too large we convert it to "lossy" style, in which we
> only remember which pages contain matching tuples instead of remembering
> each tuple individually.  When that happens, the table-visiting phase
> has to examine each tuple on the page and recheck the scan condition to
> see which tuples to return.

Comment: This makes sense once you've learned what a page is and how it stores tuples (row). I read about this at https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy.

Answer (score 36):

It is a potential re-check of the condition that is not always performed.

Only if the bitmap is *lossy* (which `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` will indicate) the recheck is performed.

A bitmap index scan becomes lossy if `work_mem` is not big enough to contain a bitmap that contains one bit per table row. It will then degrade to one bit per 8K page. Rows from such blocks will have to be rechecked.